# Узнать какое radio выделено

Tags: javascript

Есть группа radio

```
   <label for="vr1">Батон</label><br> <input type="radio" name="podog" id="vr1" value="vr1" checked><label for="vr2">Шоколад</label><br> <input type="radio" name="podog" id="vr2" value="vr2"><label for="vr3">Колбаса</label><br> <input type="radio" name="podog" id="vr3" value="vr3"><label for="vr4">Карты</label><br> <input type="radio" name="podog" id="vr4" value="vr4"><label for="vr5">Пачка чая</label><br> <input type="radio" name="podog" id="vr5" value="vr5">
```

Как при помощи js узнать какое radio выделено

Answer (score 1):

так http://jsfiddle.net/SVjtw/

Comment: **какая** кнопка....

Comment: @eicto, Вам что-то не понравилось?

Comment: да, вы получаете "выделена кнопка или нет" это не отвечает на вопрос ТС.

Comment: @eicto, лучше? http://jsfiddle.net/SVjtw/3/

Comment: мне кажется имелось ввиду в какой нибудь другой момент времени, вот есть 10 кнопок, надо найти которая выделена.

Comment: типа так http://jsfiddle.net/SVjtw/4/ (не кроссбраузерно)

Comment: @eicto, так?)) http://jsfiddle.net/SVjtw/5/